# Read DOM object after the invoke call

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, dom, browser

How can i read the value of the callback message from a javascript call.

Here is my code:

```
 private void OnDocumentLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      CallbackHandler callback = new CallbackHandler(EndRequestNormally, EndRequestWithNoData);
      SendJavaScript(CreateRequestCompleteListenerScript());

        theBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("RequestCompleteListener", new object[] { callback });
        theBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("AjaxObjectHandle", new object[] { _parameters });
    }

 private void EndRequestNormally()
    {
        SetWebWidgetWindowSize();
    }

 private void SendJavaScript(string script)
    {
        theBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] {script});
    }

 private string CreateRequestCompleteListenerScript()
    {
        StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
        script.AppendLine("var RequestCompleteListener = function(callback) {");
        script.AppendLine("    var internalCallback = {");
        script.AppendLine("        handleCallback:function(message, params){");
        script.AppendLine("            if (message == null){");
        script.AppendLine("                 callback.HandleNullMessage();");
        script.AppendLine("            } else {");
        script.AppendLine("                 callback.HandleRequestComplete();");
        script.AppendLine("            }");
        script.AppendLine("        }");
        script.AppendLine("    }");
        script.AppendLine("    UpdateAjaxObject.addListener('requestcomplete', internalCallback.handleCallback, internalCallback);");
        script.AppendLine("};");
        return script.ToString();
    }



    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
    public class CallbackHandler
    {
        public CallbackHandler(VoidHandler requestCompleteAction, VoidHandler nullMessageAction)
        {
            _requestCompleteAction = requestCompleteAction;
            _nullMessageAction = nullMessageAction;
        }

        private VoidHandler _requestCompleteAction;
        private VoidHandler _nullMessageAction;
        private bool _requestCompleted;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispId(0)]
        public void HandleRequestComplete()
        {
            if (!_requestCompleted)
                _requestCompleteAction();
            _requestCompleted = true;
        }

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispId(1)]
        public void HandleNullMessage()
        {
            if (!_requestCompleted)
                _nullMessageAction();
        }
    }
```

The above code is just making the call.

What i want is, to read the value in the message after the call.

The image below contains the values in the AJAX object

I want to get the count of the binshares under tradeschedule.
[image: Image of DOM]

Is there a way to that?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you just want to get at it with JavaScript? `<script>alert(AjaxObject.messages.tradeSchedule.binShares[0]);</script>`  You didn't expand the binShares array so I'm not sure what's under there.

I see you made changes, you want the length of binShares, do this...

`<script>alert(AjaxObject.messages.tradeSchedule.binShares.length);</script>`

Comment: Hey.. I just want the count 10 as a result (0- 9). Do not care what is inside binshares.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. Instead of an alert can i get the vaue in a variable which i can use in my C# code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with c# but if it's anything like PHP/ColdFusion then that code runs first and it produces the HTML/JavaScript, thus you can have it make JavaScript code/variables, but not the reverse (cause the server code has already completed).  There are other ways though.  This ajax call that results this big object, is it a call to one of your c# pages or something external to your site?

Comment: I am seeing the alert with the correct value but am not able to find a way to retrieve it. What this call is doing is taking the parameters from my C# code and passing it to a website which has a backend code in Java to calculate based on the parameters provided and display results. In the end i just get a callback if the request completed or not.